# Enhancing the telnet connection read input speed

Tags: java, performance, telnet

I wrote a "expect" kind of implementation for sending commands to routers.

What I am observing is, much slower processing of input from connection.

My code is as follows,

```
public static String expect(String expectString) {
        try {
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
                expectBuffer.append((char) c);
                System.out.print((char) c);
                if (expectBuffer.toString().contains(expectString)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            String expBuff = expectBuffer.toString();
            expectBuffer.setLength(0);
//            System.out.println(expBuff);
            return expBuff;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }

    }

    public static void send(String cmd) {
        pw.print(cmd + "\r");
        pw.flush();
    }
```

From the `main`, I calling them as like below,

```
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server, 23), 10000);//Will wait for 10 seconds
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
            expectBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            expect("Login");
            send("dinesh");
            expect("Password");
            send("stack");
            expect(server + "#");
            send("some command here");
            expect(server + "#");
```

It is taking much time to process the input and printing the same in the console.

Can anyone provide suggestions on improvement of my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you use a different telnet client does the router respond more quickly than you're seeing in your code? Beyond that, at a quick glance, don't do single byte reads from your buffer, do bulk reads via read(byte[], offset, length)

Comment: Also for sendIing be sure to enable tcpnodelay. unrelated suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the int read(byte[] b) function of InputStream, instead of int read().

That will speed up the reading a lot, since the information arrives in packages that are larger that 1.

Comment: I agree, though I am not sure how much it will improve things.  Been nice if we had an idea what "slow" and "fast" were in this case.

Comment: My guess is that it's the .contains function call that is run for every byte that takes up the majority of the time, by adding bytes in chunks that can be greatly reduced.

Comment: Disagree. Contains returns quickly if lengths do not match. Your suggestion is still a good one.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison This is somewhat going of on a limb, but I think that you might confuse .contains with .equals, .contains searches in the string for the substring, check the source here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java :)